# Custom Facebook Action

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

In the Facebook Graph, I have a built-in Facebook object created called movie which has object properties named 'Title', 'Description' etc and I use this using the call

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/[ns]:watch?movie=http://www.example.com/movie.html&desc='nice movie'&___` etc..

Now I created a custom object named 'opera' and the properties are of the form :

```
og:url - URL
og:title - String
og:image - Image[]
og:description - String
```

How would I use this such that the post on the users wall would be 'User' watched the 'Opera' *_*

Can I use og tags as part of my request URL? or can I use it as :

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/[ns]:watch?opera=http://www.example.com/opera.html&title='opera title'`*_* etc...

I am quite confused on how to use it in the same way as the movie object is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the tags in the call or rather you cannot.

If you want to have different pages (objects) of `opera` (type) then you need to add that in your app settings by creating a new object type and create pages (objects) of that type.

View the recipe example: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/

```
 <meta property="fb:app_id"           content="YOUR_APP_ID" /> 
 <meta property="og:type"             content="recipebox:recipe" /> 
 <meta property="og:title"            content="Chocolate Chip Cookies" /> 
 <meta property="og:image"            content="http://www.example.com/cookies.png" /> 
 <meta property="og:description"      content="Best Cookies on Earth!" /> 
 <meta property="recipebox:chef"      content="http://www.example.com/john_smith"/>
```

If your page (object) has defined it's meta tags in the `<head>` section then you should see the title, description, etc. This is where data is pulled from for your action call.

Unfortunately

> Submissions for a custom Watch action will no longer be accepted.

so you would need to use the built-in watch action `me/video.watches`, `/me/[ns]:watch` will not be accepted.